# WebApi Post goes to Get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my `WebApi` I'm trying to add a `POST` method. I have the `GET` already working. With the addition of the `POST` method every `HTTP POST` url I try goes to the `GetByCatalog` method. How can I fix this? Probably a routing issue but I can't manage to fix it.

Customer.cs (Model)

```
[Table("tblRelatie")]
public class Customer
{
    //pkey
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key()]
    [Column("fldRelatieID")]
    public int RelatieId { get; set; }

    [Column("fldRelatieSoort")]
    public int RelatieSoort { get; set; }

    [Column("fldRelatieCode")]
    public int RelatieCode { get; set; }

    [Column("fldNaam")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [Column("fldContactpersoon")]
    public string Contactpersoon { get; set; }

    [Column("fldAdres")]
    public string Adres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldPostcode")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Column("fldPlaats")]
    public string Plaats { get; set; }

    //fkey
    [Column("fldLandID")]
    public int? LandId { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCorrespondentieAdresContactpersoon")]
    public string CorrespondentieAdresContactpersoon { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCorrespondentieAdres")]
    public string CorrespondentieAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCorrespondentieAdresPostcode")]
    public string CorrespondentieAdresPostcode { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCorrespondentieAdresPlaats")]
    public string CorrespondentieAdresPlaats { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCorrespondentieAdresLandID")]
    public int? CorrespondentieAdresLandId { get; set; }

    [Column("fldFactuurRelatieID")]
    public int? FactuurRelatieId { get; set; }

    [Column("fldTelefoon")]
    public string Telefoon { get; set; }

    [Column("fldMobieleTelefoon")]
    public string MobieleTelefoon { get; set; }

    [Column("fldFax")]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [Column("fldEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBtwNummer")]
    public string BtwNummer { get; set; }

    [Column("fldDebiteurennummer")]
    public string Debiteurennummer { get; set; }

    [Column("fldFactuurkorting")]
    public decimal? Factuurkorting { get; set; }

    [Column("fldKrediettermijn")]
    public int? Krediettermijn { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBankrekeningnummer")]
    public string Bankrekeningnummer { get; set; }

    [Column("fldNaamRekeninghouder")]
    public string NaamRekeninghouder { get; set; }

    [Column("fldPlaatsRekeninghouder")]
    public string PlaatsRekeninghouder { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBankieren")]
    public bool Bankieren { get; set; }

    [Column("fldNonactief")]
    public bool Nonactief { get; set; }

    [Column("fldKlantKortinggroepID")]
    public int? KlantKortinggroepId { get; set; }

    [Column("fldKredietLimiet")]
    public decimal? KredietLimiet { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBestelBedragMinimum")]
    public decimal? BestelBedragMinimum { get; set; }

    [Column("fldMemo")]
    public string Memo { get; set; }

    [Column("fldKvkNummer")]
    public string KvkNummer { get; set; }

    [Column("fldCreditcardNummer")]
    public string CreditcardNummer { get; set; }

    [Column("fldWebsiteUrl")]
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }

    [Column("fldAanmanen")]
    public int? Aanmanen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldElektronischFactureren")]
    public bool ElektronischFactureren { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteEmailen")]
    public bool? OfferteEmailen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteEmailAdres")]
    public string OfferteEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteCcEmailAdres")]
    public string OfferteCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBevestigingEmailen")]
    public bool? BevestigingEmailen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBevestigingEmailAdres")]
    public string BevestigingEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBevestigingCcEmailAdres")]
    public string BevestigingCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldFactuurEmailAdres")]
    public string FactuurEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldFactuurCcEmailAdres")]
    public string FactuurCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldAanmaningEmailen")]
    public bool? AanmaningEmailen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldAanmaningEmailAdres")]
    public string AanmaningEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldAanmaningCcEmailAdres")]
    public string AanmaningCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteAanvraagEmailen")]
    public bool? OfferteAanvraagEmailen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteAanvraagEmailAdres")]
    public string OfferteAanvraagEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldOfferteAanvraagCcEmailAdres")]
    public string OfferteAanvraagCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBestellingEmailen")]
    public bool? BestellingEmailen { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBestellingEmailAdres")]
    public string BestellingEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBestellingCcEmailAdres")]
    public string BestellingCcEmailAdres { get; set; }

    [Column("fldUblBestandAlsBijlage")]
    public bool UblBestandAlsBijlage { get; set; }

    [Column("fldUblLeverancierNaamHide")]
    public string UblLeverancierNaamHide { get; set; }

    [Column("fldIban")]
    public string Iban { get; set; }

    [Column("fldBic")]
    public string Bic { get; set; }

    [Column("fldIncasseren")]
    public int? Incasseren { get; set; }

}
```

CustomerController.cs

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all customers from a catalog
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="catalog">The catalog (administration) name</param>
    /// <returns>All customers in the specified catalog</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetByCatalog(string catalog)
    {
        using (var db = new CustomerContext(Extensions.BuildConnectionString(catalog)))
        {
            return db.Customers.ToList();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Customer Post(string catalog, [FromUri] Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Customer");
        }

        using (var db = new CustomerContext(Extensions.BuildConnectionString(catalog)))
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return customer;
        }
    }
```

CustomerContext.cs

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext(string sConnectionString)
        : base(sConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Http Post url

> http://localhost:56909/api/customer/Post?catalog=Kopie&relatiesoort=1&relatiecode=300850&naam=pieter&contactpersoon=pieter&adres=straat&postcode=8794PO&plaats=adam&landid=1&correspondentieadrescontactpersoon=adres&correspondentieadres=straat&correspondentieadrespostcode=8415PO&correspondentieadresplaats=amsterdam&correspondentieadreslandid=1&factuurrelatieid=1&telefoon=0147885665&mobieletelefoon=06559889&fax=0582184&email=test@test.com&btwnummer=688658&debiteurennummer=74498&factuurkorting=12,20&krediettermijn=30&bankrekeningnummer=6554561&naamrekeninghouder=lol&plaatsrekeninghouder=adam&bankieren=true&nonactief=false&klantkortinggroepid=1&kredietlimiet=10,000&bestelbedragminimum=100,00&memo=oude%20klant&kvknummer=665665&creditcardnummer=868658658&websiteurl=test.nl&aanmanen=1&elektronischfactureren=true&offerteemailen=false&offerteemailadres=klant@klant.nl&offerteccemailadres=klant@klant.nl&bevestigingemailen=false&bevestigingemailadres=test@test.com&bevestigingccemailadres=test@test.com&factuuremailadres=test@test.com&factuurccemailadres=test@test.com&aanmaningemailen=false&aanmaningemailadres=test@test.com&aanmaningccemailadres=test@test.com&offerteaanvraagemailen=false&offerteaanvraagemailadres=test@test.com&offerteaanvraagccemailadres=test@test.com&bestellingemailen=false&bestellingemailadres=test@test.com&bestellingccemailadres=test@test.com&ublbestandalsbijlage=false&ublleveranciernaamhide=nee&iban=8688434&bic=8748&incasseren=1

Edit:

I'm using the `NuGet Package` `WebAPITestClient` now to do the request it works perfect after the suggested modifications of **atornblad**

Comment: A POST sends data through the body of the request. You are attempting to "post" on the url, which you cannot do.

Comment: How do you call the POST method? I suspect you are using the GET verb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you posted at the end hints that you are not actually using `POST` to make the request, but actually `GET`. You should **NOT** include the /Post in the url. The Web API infrastructure takes care of that for you if you do a `POST` to http://localhost:56909/api/customer instead! All the values passed in the URL should actually be passed as POST data, and not as query string values, and you really should remove the `[FromUri]` attribute.

I do not know what framework *(if any)* you are using to make the request from the browser, but please make sure you are `POST`-ing and not `GET`-ting.

**IF** you are using jQuery, take a look at how to correctly perform a `POST` request here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Otherwise, look at your framework's documentation. Also, if you edit your post to include the client-side code *(JavaScript)*, I could update this answer to be more in line with your conditions.

Comment: I'm only using `Entity Framework` as a framework in my WebApi. I don't use any JS (yet). The call to the `GET` is done by `http://localhost:56909/api/customer/GetByCatalog?catalog=MyDB`

Comment: Then you are not using WebApi correctly. You should re-check the WebApi documentation and rethink your use of WebApi. You are not registering your WebApi routes correctly. Your methods should be named `Get()`, `Post()`, and possibly other **HTTP** verb names. WebApi is for creating rich client-side functionality using Ajax.

Comment: I'm using the `NuGet Package` `WebAPITestClient` now to do the request,  I got the `POST` working after your suggested modifications.

Comment: Any idea how to specify the `POST` `"RelatieId"` it's an identity (I don't want to pass a value) how to format it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you don't want to pass a value? Should it be left out of the request completely? Do you want to pass it in the URL? You shold probably not use your internal database entities for public APIs like this, because it makes it very difficult to make changes to the behavior of your API.

Comment: I added the `JSON` body, as you know for identity columns you want them to generate their own value but if I leave out the `RelatieId` of the `JSON` the request fails

Comment: Nevermind I made a mistake in another field of the JSON body the identity column works if I leave it out of the body.